# Vagrant in silent/quiet mode

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I would like to disable the stdout for Vagrant, at the moment it prints all the steps as it goes through the Vagrantfile, how can I make vagrant to show failure or warning only?

I use puppet and shell provisioner with it.

I don't want to see this type of output unless there is an error or warning.

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Cloning VM...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'puppetlabs/ubuntu-14.04-64-puppet' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: puppet4-test-puppet4
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the standard stdout to null and it should retain only what is pushing on stderr

```
$ vagrant up > /dev/null
```

Comment: That's helpful however it purges the error messages from provisioner ( Puppet) since this is not a Vagrant error. Any idea how can I still be able to see errors like this one:

`==> default: Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type`

Comment: I think vagrant reports at the end that the provisioner had error, but you dont have the detail its true - maybe you need to redirect stdout into a file then and in case of error you need to go through this file, I dont see any other way as of now